# Размеры и координаты области в JFrame, где можно рисовать

Tags: java, jframe

Как в Java узнать размеры и координаты области (прямоугольник по сути) в JFrame, где можно рисовать?
То есть не считая границы JFrame и верхнюю ее часть.

Answer (score 1):

Решил задачу путем добавления двух строчек кода перед тем, как узнать размеры доступного пространства.

```
this.setVisible(true);
this.setVisible(false);
```

Не знаю почему, но так работает. 
После добавления `this.setVisible(true);` размер становится известен.
Сразу после этого использую `this.setVisible(false);`, т.к. дальнейшие компоненты, добавленные на панель не отображаются.
Само собой, в конце опять использую `this.setVisible(true);`

Answer (score 0):

Для получения размеров области используйте:

```
frame.getContentPane().getSize();
```

Перед этим у вас обязательно должно стоять `frame.pack()`

---

Для координат используйте [`JFrame`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html) методы [`getLocation()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getLocation()) или [`getLocationOnScreen()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getLocationOnScreen()), которые унаследованы от java.awt.Component.

Comment: Когда использую frame.pack() окно становится нулевого размера, а мне нужен определенный размер.